# TALLY - http header DISABLELOG is not disabling http logging

Tags: xml, http, tally

I read the following documentation from Tally:

> In order to explicitly control the Logs, the requestor can additionally send a Header DISABLELOG, set to YES, which will disable the current log, irrespective of the Configuration or the Mode in which Tally is running. The default value is NO, i.e., in the absence of this Header, the HTTP Information will be logged to the file TallyHTTP.log, if Tally.ERP 9 is working in Developer Mode and HTTP Log is enabled in Configuration.

When I am sending http request (in XML format) to Tally (localhost:9000) with a header 
DIABLELOG: Yes, Tally is not throwing any error message but continues to log the http request in the Tallyhttp.log file in Tally's directory.

My goal is to carry out data exchange with Tally without the logging of request XMLs. I am testing using ARC google chrome extension.

My http request header is the following:

```
content-type:
text/xml; charset=utf-8
disablelog: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a sample XML request that you are making?

I think there could be a case sensitive issue as well.

I would also suggest using ngrok to test your requests and headers to see what is actually being sent and received in detail.

Comment: The XML I am sending to Tally is:

<ENVELOPE>
 <HEADER>
  <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
 </HEADER>
 <BODY>
  <EXPORTDATA>
   <REQUESTDESC>
    <REPORTNAME>List of Accounts</REPORTNAME>
    <STATICVARIABLES>
     <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Varra Crafts</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
     <ACCOUNTTYPE>Units</ACCOUNTTYPE>
    </STATICVARIABLES>
   </REQUESTDESC>
  </EXPORTDATA>
 </BODY>
</ENVELOPE> 

Before posting, I am sending headers:

IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['DISABLELOG'] := 'Yes';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml;charset=UTF-16';

I am using Delphi 7.

Comment: Yes I tried it via CURL and logged the requests via ngrok. And it is still logging to tallyhttp.log